# data.table equivalent of dplyr::%in% using the ! (not) operator

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Is there an equivalent version of the following code in the data.table package syntax in R?

the following line of code filters down the mtcars dataset for rows that **do not contain** the cyl values in the set (4,6)

Within dplyr this code looks like:

```
mtcars %>% filter(!(cyl %in% c(4,6)))
```

Is there an equivalent syntax in data.table that performs a %in% operation which is nested by a ! not operator to filter down rows in a table?

you can run the example by the following code:

```
library(tidyverse) 
mtcars %>% filter(!(cyl %in% c(4,6)))
```

Comment: Seems to be an open issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4152

Comment: @MrFlick Damn - did not see this as an open issue nor if one even existed! I guess I may wait - or just convert back to tibble then data.table

Comment: `as.data.table(mtcars)[!cyl %in% c(4,6),]` works for me, am I missing something?

Comment: Also `%in%` is not a dplyr function. It's a base R function. It should still work in data.table.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why this was a question? Was it just a lack of understanding how to do subsetting in Pkg:data.table? The open issue is not whether that works but whether it gets parsed and evaluated as an optimized data.table function.

Comment: @42- There is scarce information regarding subsetting in this format using the package data.table which is why I asked the question. The open issue is related to parsing only.

Comment: I emphatically disagree.   will agree that searching might be a bit confusing, but that is only because there are so many hits to an SO search: `[r] [subset] [data.table]`. (200+ hits) Also using the help system with `?subset` (with the data.table package loaded, or `help(subset, pack=data.table)`

Comment: @42- This question and the accepted answer will at least help those who come across a similar problem in future - I was unaware of using the ?subset function and will research it in future - thank you for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? Below is how to subset rows in `data.table`. Comparing to your `dplyr` code, the part `!(cyl %in% c(4,6))` is exactly the same as your original code. So in this case, the only thing you need to learn is `dt[..code.., ]` is the equivalent as the `df %>% filter(..code..)`, where `..code..` is a logical statement to evaluate the condition of each row.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- mtcars
setDT(dat)[!(cyl %in% c(4,6)), ]
#      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#  1: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#  2: 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#  3: 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#  4: 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#  5: 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#  6: 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#  7: 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#  8: 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#  9: 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
# 10: 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
# 11: 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
# 12: 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
# 13: 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
# 14: 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: works well - seems to filter down to the correct rows!

Comment: Perhaps worth stating explicitly that, in general, `df %>% filter(..code..)` in `dplyr` is the same as `dt[..code.., ]` or `subset(dt, ..code..)` in data table. Nothing special about `x %in% y` or `!(x %in% y)` or any other expression that returns logical values.

Comment: @GregorThomas Great suggestion. I have modified my post based on your suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `subset` method for data.tables. It has the same syntax as the `data.frame` method:

```
dat <- mtcars
subset( setDT(dat), !(cyl %in% c(4,6))  )
#-----------------
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 1: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
 2: 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
 3: 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
 4: 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
 5: 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
 6: 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
 7: 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
 8: 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
 9: 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
10: 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
11: 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
12: 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
13: 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
14: 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

See `?subset.data.table`